# Routing Errors & Actions not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im going through a tutorial on Ruby on Rails and am ready to shoot myself.

**1st Question:**
applications/html/erb it keeps telling me "Rails actions 'index', 'about', and 'help' could not be found. However when I am on the localhost3000/site/index I can navigate through the pages just fine. Any idea why it's telling my the actions can't be found?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= @title %></title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css' %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="whole_page">
          <div id="header">Work<b>Link</b></div>
            <div id= "nav">
              <%= link_to_unless_current 'Home', action: 'index' %> |
              <%= link_to_unless_current 'About Us', action: 'about' %> |
              <%= link_to_unless_current 'Help', action: 'help' %>
            </div>
         <div id="content">
           <%= @content_for_layout %>
           <%= yield %>
         </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**2nd Question**:
However when I try to load a different controller page localhost3000/users/register it flips out and gives me errors. It keeps telling there is a problem with **No route matches [GET] "/user/index"**

This is my Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/index'

  get 'users/register'

  get 'site/index'

  get 'site/about'

  get 'site/help'

  root 'site#index'
```

Ive been fumbling around with this all day and can't seem to find the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `routes` definitions are incorrect.

For example, for `user#index` you should have to tell Rails which controller action to call when it matches that particular route in the url:

```
get '/users', to: 'users#index'
```

This means, when you hit a url like `localhost:3000/users` it will match this route and will call the `UsersController`'s `index` action.

Alternatively, you could make use of Rails convention of defining `resourceful routes` and have:

```
resources :users
```

in your `routes` file, then Rails will create all the CRUD routes for your application:

```
          users GET    /users(.:format)                        users#index
                POST   /users(.:format)                        users#create
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
```

I highly recommend you to read the [Rails official documentation for Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: so it should be `get 'user#index'` ? I get an error on that.

Comment: `get /users` would be fine

Answer (score 0):

If you only provide an action the link-helpers will try to link to an action with that name in the controller currently rendering the action. So when your rendering from different controllers you will also have to give a value for the key `controller:`.

Comment: can you give me an example. Im super new to this stuff.

Comment: Which controllers do you have? Lets say you have a `SitesController` defining an action `help`. Then you'll have to write `link_to_unless_current 'Help', action: 'help', controller: 'sites' `. Also fix your routes as mentioned below.

Comment: Wonderful! And what do you mean regarding fixing the routes.

Comment: The answer K M Rakibul Islam gave